# How to autofill jsp textbox using database values without using buttons or submit?

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp, servlets

I have a submit form in a jsp page. Whenever I enter that page that textboxes should be filled with database values. So that I can edit that and submit to be saved in the database. I have a servlet page which has variables having database values. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the process for programming web pages is the following:

- Servlet (the controller) receives request to edit data.
- The servlet will then call the database or the code that represents the database and get the needed data.
- That data (the model) can be used directly or modified to work for the specific view.
- Then that data (the model) is added the to HttpServletResponse object as an attribute and forwarded on to the jsp.
- The jsp (the view) then uses that data (the model) to fill the form's fields as needed.
- The form is then submitted to another servlet that takes the imputed data, validates it, and then commits the newly entered data to the database or the code that represents the database.

Comment: Sorry its not like that here, I'm not using any framework . Its just a simple program. Whenever I enter that page with textboxes that values should be already filled in the textboxes. So that I can change that values if needed and sumbitted.

Comment: @Vignesh You tagged the question with `servlets` - this answer does not mention any other *framework*

Comment: @Vignesh, the description above is about as simple as it can be for a low level, semi-professional application.  There are ways of doing all the work that you're asking for directly in a jsp, but those techniques are highly discouraged.

Comment: Thanks, but could you please make clear how to get that values filled whenever that page is loaded.

Comment: Here is the simplest example I could find:  [How to put an object on the request in a servlet](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/servlets/how-put-object-request-httpservletrequest-servlet).  Start with something small, like a static object created in your servlet, pass that object to your jsp, print it out.  Then add the html form and fill in the textfields.  Then submit that data and print it out in another servlet, etc...

Comment: I can already get the output using scriplet tage in jsp, but I dont want to use java code in jsp, So iam lokking for something jquery or else.

Comment: So, the above example maybe wasn't the best since it uses scriplets.  This is a better example:  [Java Servlet Set/Get Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/servlet/java-servlet-set-get-example/).  The important code is the following:  `<%= request.getAttribute("mySecretMessage") %>`  You could do something similar, but in a html text field:  `<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<%= request.getAttribute("firstName") %>>`